Heating a Material with Negative temperature coefficient of resistance
TCR (Temperature Coefficient of Resistance): $R = R_0[1 + α(T - T₀)]$ Where: $R$ is the resistance at temperature $T$, $R_0$ is the resistance at a reference temperature $T_0$, $\alpha$ is the TCR of the material (in Ω/Ω/°C or 1/°C)
Joule's law: $P = I^2 R$ Where: $P$ is the power dissipated (in watts) $I$ is the current flowing through the resistor (in amperes) R is the resistance of the material (in ohms)
Problem: If a material has $α=-5×10^{-4}$, can that material be heated up using a current? If R decreases, I would increase since I = V/R (assuming power supply V is fixed), and P can either increase or remain the same (the increase in I compensate the decrease in R).
I'm confused which one is it?

please use mathjax

So, if you have thermal equilibrium, such that the rate of electrical heating is equal to the rate of convective heat loss from the resistor, the heat balance on the resistor reads $$\frac{V^2}{R}=hA(T-T_0)$$or $$\frac{V^2}{R_0}=hA(T-T_0)[1+\alpha(T-T_0)]$$where h is the convective heat transfer coefficient, A is the surface area of the resistor, and $T_0$ is the room temperature.  This certainly can have a real positive root for T, depending on the other parameter values.
